# Where to access the available plugin/Wordpress updates?

Tags: plugins, updates, json

I need to find out where/how I can access the plugin updates in a WordPress site[image]

Ideally I want to have these in a json format, with the entire list of plugin updates available.

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plugin update data is cached in the `update_plugins` site transient with available updates under the `response` property.

```
$data = get_site_transient( 'update_plugins' );
var_dump( $data->response );
```

Response looks a bit like:

```
array(1) {
  ["wordpress-seo/wp-seo.php"]=>
  object(stdClass)#1873 (11) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(27) "w.org/plugins/wordpress-seo"
    ["slug"]=>
    string(13) "wordpress-seo"
    ["plugin"]=>
    string(24) "wordpress-seo/wp-seo.php"
    ["new_version"]=>
    string(5) "5.5.1"
    ["url"]=>
    string(44) "https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/"
    ["package"]=>
    string(62) "https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/wordpress-seo.5.5.1.zip"
    ["icons"]=>
    array(4) {
      ["1x"]=>
      string(66) "https://ps.w.org/wordpress-seo/assets/icon-128x128.png?rev=1550389"
      ["2x"]=>
      string(66) "https://ps.w.org/wordpress-seo/assets/icon-256x256.png?rev=1550389"
      ["svg"]=>
      string(58) "https://ps.w.org/wordpress-seo/assets/icon.svg?rev=1203032"
      ["default"]=>
      string(58) "https://ps.w.org/wordpress-seo/assets/icon.svg?rev=1203032"
    }
    ["banners"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["2x"]=>
      string(69) "https://ps.w.org/wordpress-seo/assets/banner-1544x500.png?rev=1695112"
      ["1x"]=>
      string(68) "https://ps.w.org/wordpress-seo/assets/banner-772x250.png?rev=1695112"
      ["default"]=>
      string(69) "https://ps.w.org/wordpress-seo/assets/banner-1544x500.png?rev=1695112"
    }
    ["banners_rtl"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["2x"]=>
      string(73) "https://ps.w.org/wordpress-seo/assets/banner-1544x500-rtl.png?rev=1695112"
      ["1x"]=>
      string(72) "https://ps.w.org/wordpress-seo/assets/banner-772x250-rtl.png?rev=1695112"
      ["default"]=>
      string(73) "https://ps.w.org/wordpress-seo/assets/banner-1544x500-rtl.png?rev=1695112"
    }
    ["tested"]=>
    string(5) "4.8.2"
    ["compatibility"]=>
    object(stdClass)#1846 (0) {
    }
  }
}
```

Data is generated from from the dot-org plugin update check endpoint ([some limited documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress.org_API#Plugins)) and is fetched in the [`wp_update_plugins()` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_plugins/).